# Firebase Performance Monitor is crashing due to HTTP 429 Too Many Requests Response

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit2, firebase-performance

I've noticed an issue in firebase crashlytics that Firebase Performance Monitor is crashing with this stacktrace
[image: crash stacktrace]

Has anybody experienced the same issue?

The libs I'm using are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.11'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
```

Comment: If you have a bug report, file that with Firebase support.  There's not much Stack Overflow can do to help.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support